# 2D Integration With Quadratic Arg. of Delta Function

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

   I have a 2D integral that contains a delta function:

   $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp{-((x_2-x_1)^2)+(a x_2^2+b x_1^2-c x_2+d x_1+e))}\delta(p x_1^2-q x_2^2) dx_1 dx_2$,

   where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are variables, and a,b,c,d,e,p and q are some real constants.
2. Relevant equations

   How can one integrate this without resulting in poles. Because integral over, for example, $x_1$ leads to a pole, given the property of delta function.
3. The attempt at a solution
   If inside the delta function, the argument would be $x_1^2+x_2^2$, and not $x_1^2-x_2^2$, then one could go to polar coordinates, and get rid of the poles coming from the delta function integral. Sadly, this is not the case here.
   Further one can get rid of pole by going into hyperbolic coordinates $x_1=RCosh(\theta)$ and  $x_2=RSinh(\theta)$. The R integral can be done exactly because the poles cancel out due to Jacobian. However, the integral over ##\theta## then becomes unbounded. So this method also has a problem. Is there a smarter way to perform integral with quadratic argument of delta function without encountering poles?

Comment: I don't see why the integral over $\theta$ diverges. It's an exponential with the negative of squared terms or terms overcomed by the squared ones...

Comment: If I modify my problem a little, but and have the argument of the delta function as follows, I think even the $R$ integral diverges now.

if my delta looks like $\delta(p x_1^2-q x_2^2+r x_1-s x_2+\epsilon)$. the derivative over one of the coordinates doesn't just produce R but R+something. Hence it doesn't cancel with the Jacobian. But you might be correct about $\theta$ integral not diverging.

Comment: I think a better approach is the one following the [wikipedia formula for a multivariable integral with a delta composed with some function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Properties_in_n_dimensions). I tried it and the resulting integral doesn't seem to diverge. I am not sure about some details, but the path seems straight.

Comment: do you do the coordinate transform into hyperbolic functions as I mentioned earlier?

Comment: No coordinate transformation needed if you aren't said to solve that way.